# Publish webpage using IIS

Tags: iis

I am trying to create a webpage that will be available for my team members. From my personal laptop.

Today i created a basic page using following tutorial.

https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/how-to-create-website-in-iis/

But when i tried to open the page from another pc...
It didnt work.

I have added port 80 in firewall setting.
When i tried to open using my mobile.it worked. Because my laptop is connected to mobile hotspot.

But showing error as site cant be reach on outside devices.
Please help me.

Do i need to do port forwarding??? If yes then how can i do it on mobile?
As right now i can use only mobile hotspot
.

Pc OS : windows 10.

I have enabled IIS using windows feature

Is it necessary to install windows server? To be able to publish page to outside user?

Comment: In most cases you need to study computer networking instead of programming to set up the environments in the right way, https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef That's beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary to install windows server to host websites. IIS also works in Windows Client OS.
If your mobile could access the website correctly, there are might be something wrong with network connectivity causing the failure of accessing the webpage from other PC. We should ensure that the other PC is in the same network with the webserver(your laptop), just like the network of your mobile.
I advise other PC to join the mobile hotspot too. Following shutting the firewall and access the website by using the IP address again.
Considering the `Ping` tool to troubleshoot the network issue.
https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-do-a-ping-test-windows-10
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thats what i was asking... The other pc are not in same network. Let say... Other team members are at their own home. And i want my page to be accessible to them.

Comment: We should publish the service in the public network(internet), and with a unique domain name that could be accessible by anyone who has internet access. More commonly, we publish the service in the Azure/AWS cloud platform, which provides a hosting environment of the website, like the Azure app service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/deploy-a-website-with-azure-app-service/